# (RN) Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): #Redux + axios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, promise, axios

```
function requestService() {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: userEndpoint,
        headers: {
            common: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
            }
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('requestService', error);
    });
}

module.exports = {
    requestService
};
```

RequestService.js

```
    import type { PromiseAction } from "./Types";

    async function loadHopses(userId: number): PromiseAction {
        const url = `hopses/user/${userId}`
        const list = requestService().get(url);
        await InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions();
        return {
            type: "LOADED_HOPSES",
            list
        };
    }

    module.exports = {
        loadHopses
    };
```

Action.js

```
this.props.dispatch(loadHopses(1));
```

App.js

```
export type PromiseAction = Promise<Action>;
```

Types.js

---

error is 
**Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: _axios2.default.create(...).then is not a function
TypeError: _axios2.default.create(...).then is not a function**

I based on f8 facebook app and be converting parse to rest

What's wrong in this code?
please help..

Comment: axios.create gives you a new isntance are you sure you are not looking for one of [these](https://github.com/axios/axios#instance-methods)  instance methods

Comment: requestService().get(url); is that methods, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

axios.create returns an instance like this:

```
var instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

These are the only valid methods for that.

```
axios#request(config)
axios#get(url[, config])
axios#delete(url[, config])
axios#head(url[, config])
axios#options(url[, config])
axios#post(url[, data[, config]])
axios#put(url[, data[, config]])
axios#patch(url[, data[, config]])
```

You can instead use it like this:

```
return axios.({
    method: 'post',
    baseURL: userEndpoint,
    headers: {
        common: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
        }
    }
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

Using `axios()` instead of `axios.create()`